# JQuery Datatable initialized twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatable, datatables

Datatable on ASP.NET CORE Razor Page is initialized twice. Any idea what could be wrong or how to avoid this issue?
[image: This what I see if I run the code in browser console]

Simple table

```
@page
@model NewSolution.Pages.IndexModel
 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 
<table id="table" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        </tr>
</table>
 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

initialization on load - this is working fine

```
//initializeDatatable
function initializeDatatable() {
    $('#table').DataTable();
};
initializeDatatable();
```

if I run the following code in browser console, datatable is getting initialized twice

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable().data();
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code,and datatable will not get initialized twice.
View:

```
<table id="table" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        </tr>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            function initializeDatatable() {
                $('#table').DataTable();
            };
            initializeDatatable();
        })
    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could find the issue.
There is additional script called on Layout page and this has to be removed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```